# How do I force Firefox to always show the "Restore Session" page after closing (but never attempt to automatically re-open all my tabs)?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, restore

Quite often I amass a huge number of tabs in Firefox so I kill the browser processes to recover RAM.

To kill it I use `taskkill /f /im firefox.exe`.

When I start Firefox again it automatically tries to re-open all of my tabs which I don't want it to do -- I want it to remember my previous session but not automatically restore it.

This is exactly what the "Session Restore" page does (it shows the previous session in a big list but doesn't auto-restore it) but that page is only shown [after a crash](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/restore-previous-session#w_after-a-crash).

One way of forcing the "Session Restore" list to appear is to kill Firefox multiple times in a row (i.e. simulate a crash) but this doesn't always work which is really annoying.

So... how do I force Firefox to always start on the "Restore Session" page by default and never attempt to auto-restore my previous session?

And as a bonus question: is there a more elegant way of killing Firefox than my command above?

Comment: I think you might be able to control the restore process better by using the [Session Manager](http://sessionmanager.mozdev.org/) extension. The way you're killing the processes is the best way I know of.

Comment: Also, I believe there's another Firefox extension that will add a menu item or toolbar button that will restart the application. Can't remember the name of it.